# How to fix "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;" in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'COUNT(a.buy_id) AS Total_buy
> FROM DAS AS a
> JOIN
> (SELECT
> ' at line 3

The whole code is as below:

```
SELECT
           a.team_leader
           COUNT(a.buy_id) AS Total_buy
FROM DAS AS a
JOIN 
       (SELECT
                  b.team_leader
                  COUNT(DISTINCT b.user_id) AS Customers_Who_Ordered
        FROM DAS AS b
        WHERE b.processing_at BETWEEN “01-07-2020” AND “31-07-2020”
        GROUP BY b.team_leader)
ON a.team_leader = b.team_leader
GROUP BY a.team_leader
ORDER BY Total_buy DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `,` after `SELECT a.team_leader`. It should be `SELECT a.team_leader, COUNT(a.buy_id)...`

You need to do the same in the other `select` query — `SELECT b.team_leader, COUNT(DISTINCT b.user_id)...`

```sql
SELECT a.team_leader,
       COUNT(a.buy_id) AS Total_buy
FROM DAS AS a
JOIN
  (SELECT b.team_leader,
          COUNT(DISTINCT b.user_id) AS Customers_Who_Ordered
   FROM DAS AS b
   WHERE b.processing_at BETWEEN "01-07-2020" AND "31-07-2020"
   GROUP BY b.team_leader) AS b
ON a.team_leader = b.team_leader
GROUP BY a.team_leader
ORDER BY Total_buy DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: The joined subquery needs an alias.

Comment: @P.Salmon Good catch! Just added it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the commas after SELECT a.team_leader **,** COUNT....